# how do i get my website on another website using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to make a script that will display my business admin site on another website so they can use it without having to go through installing it. I want to do what google does with their Translator:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
```

i would also like to keep track of the people that buy it and so i can terminate there connection if they are not paying there monthly fee or go against the t&c and the only way i can think of doing that is use a key that is saved in a db

Comment: The simplest way is to use an `IFrame`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: could i add a key to iframes that links the end user to a database so that i can stop them using it if i need to terminate there access

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [iframes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp).

**Iframe Syntax**:

```
<iframe src="URL"></iframe>
```

Just add that to your html and replace "URL" with the url of the desired embedded site.

Comment: i thought about iframes but i heard that they can be evil to use even more so when passing data to a db and i would like to keep track of the people that buy it and so i can terminate there connection if they are not paying there monthly fee or go against the t&c and the only way i can think of doing that is use a key that is saved in a db

Answer (score 1):

You can display another website using open window in javascript.

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```